# Hyperledger-Composer permission: Read only specific type of transaction from HistorianRecord

Tags: permissions, hyperledger-composer

I am trying to create a Hyperledger Business network using Hyperledger Composer. I have a **Guest** participant who have only READ permission on specific type of transactions when request from **HistorianRecord** (e.g. only see all Trade transactions from HistorianRecord)

I already searched [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/unstable/reference/historian.html) and notice that each transaction has a field ***transactionType***. So I wrote a rule for Guest in **permission.acl**

```
rule R14_GuestCanSeeTradeHistoryOnly {
  description: "Guest should be able to see the history of trade transactions only"
  participant(g): "org.example.mynetwork.Guest"
  operation: READ
  resource(v): "org.hyperledger.composer.system.HistorianRecord"
  condition: (v.transactionType == "org.example.mynetwork.Trade")
  action: ALLOW
}
```

However, when I deployed the business network and test with **Hyperledger Playground**, access to **guest@tutorial-network** card and view All Transactions, the guest participant still can see all transactions (include system transactions and other participants's transactions), which is not allowed. The guest participant should only see the Trade transactions

Is there any way to specify the rule in file **permission.acl** that meet my requirement? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check the Rule 3 in this documentation, it seems similar to what you want to do: https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/acl-trading

Comment: @Riccardo thanks for the answer. i already read that document. but in my case, **guest** just a participant who has permission to view *Trade* transaction historical records. i can use [query](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/v0.19/tutorials/queries) instead, but it seems like we cannot set permission rules for query so all other participants can also request to use that query (they are not supposed to do so). i think the acceptable solution is create a new transaction that has query inside, then set permission that only **guest** participant can view